# How to do I stop text from overflowing from input

Tags: html, textarea

Say I type in 5000 words in a textarea box that gets stored in a database and then call it onto the page. What can I do so it stops at a certain point and travels starts on the next row?

Comment: You mean you want to split it into paragraphs at certain intervals?

Comment: Yes. http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=12&id=12 See here to see my problem.

Comment: keeping `spans` inside a `p` is a bad practice, and use css to cut the length down.

Comment: @karthik what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `word_wrap`

```
$formated_string = wordwrap($str,1000,"<br>",true);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php